# Why does error No module named app keep coming up?

Tags: python, visual-studio, flask

Not sure why I keep getting this error.

The app.py seems to be in the right folder and there's no virtual env folder.

> Error (python.exe: No module named app)

[image]

It is a Flask app.  This is literally all of the code (It's a school project but I don't think the error is part of it):

```
from flask 

import Flask, render_template
import json

"""
A example for creating a Table that is sortable by its header
"""
app = Flask(__name__)
data = [{
  "name": "bootstrap-table",
  "commits": "10",
  "uneven": "An extended Bootstrap table"
},
 {
  "name": "multiple-select",
  "commits": "288",
  "uneven": "A jQuery plugin"
}, {
  "name": "Testing",
  "commits": "340",
  "uneven": "For test"
}]
# other column settings -> http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#column-options
columns = [
  {
    "field": "name", # which is the field's name of data key 
    "title": "name", # display as the table header's name
    "sortable": True,
  },
  {
    "field": "commits",
    "title": "commits",
    "sortable": True,
  },
  {
    "field": "uneven",
    "title": "uneven",
    "sortable": True,
  }
]

#jdata=json.dumps(data)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("table.html",
      data=data,
      columns=columns,
      title='Flask Bootstrap Table')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #print jdata
  app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace of your application as well as the exact code, not only images!

Comment: maybe add how you are running your script? Seems like a flask app, are you trying to run app.py or are you running some other command?

Comment: I added the entire script above. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below link, it seems to be a similar problem

[Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5317169/Python-modulenotfounderror-is-name-of-app)